# All positive integers a and b such that $a! + 6 = b^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, factorial

I'm not sure how to approach proving solutions for this problem.
I wrote a python program which shows a  must be $\geq 30$, but I don't understand why.

```
import math
a=0
while a < 1000:
    a = a + 1
    Q = ( (math.factorial(a))+6 )**.5
    if Q.is_integer():
        print("a is ",a," b is ",Q)
```

But, I don't know how to prove all solutions. How should I approach this problem? Thank you

Comment: For most $a$, $a!+6\equiv6\pmod 7$.

Answer (score 5):

If $a\geq 6$ then $3\mid a!+6\implies 3\mid b$ so $b=3c$ and thus $9\mid a!+6$ so $3\mid {a!\over 3}+2 $.

Now since $3\mid {a!\over 3}$ we get $3\mid 2$ a contradiction. So $a<6$.

If $a=5$ so $126 =b^2$ a contradiction.

If $a=4$ so $30 =b^2$ a contradiction.

If $a=3$ so $12 =b^2$ a contradiction.

If $a=2$ so $8 =b^2$ a contradiction.

If $a=1$ so $7 =b^2$ a contradiction.

So we have no such pairs.

Comment: This is a very clean solution. I was thinking of writing an answer using modular work, but I find your answer to be more elementarily accessible and nice. I might write $ 3 \mid \big( \tfrac{a!}{3} + 2 \big)$ to make it clearer what divides what, but this is perhaps a stylistic choice.

Answer (score 0):

for an integer $a$, $a!$ is also an integer.
let $A=a!$, so:
$$A+6=b^2$$
now we know that $A\ge1$ due to the limitations of the factorial function for integer values.
By running through values of $A$ you can find $b$, now work back and go through a list of $n!$ and $A$ to see which is equal. This seems like the easiest way

Answer (score 0):

If $a \ge 7$ then $7|a!$ and $b^2 =a! + 6 \equiv -1 \pmod 7$.

But $b^2 \equiv -1\pmod {odd\ prime}$ has no solution.

So if there is any solution $a < 7$.

We can just check them one after another.

$1+6=7;2+6=8; 6+6=12;24+6=30; 120+6=126; 720+6 = 726$ and none of those are square.

(For what it's worth I didn't come up with testing for $7$ right away.  I first figured that if $a \ge 6$ [actually $a\ge 3$] then $6|a!+6$ and so $6|b$.  Then for all $k \le a$ that $b^2 \equiv 6 \pmod k$ and then $b^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$ and $b^2 \equiv -1 \pmod 7$ seemed fruitful....)

Answer (score 0):

If $a\ge 4$ then $4\mid {a!}$
$\implies$ $$b^{2}\equiv 6\pmod4$$
$\implies$ $$b^{2}\equiv 2\pmod4$$
This is impossible.
So there are no pairs $(a,b)$ satisfying this equation.